# Best way to send data and calculate CRC for large application - embedded application

Tags: c#, c, embedded, crc, i2c

I need advice and suggestions on the protocol to properly write a .bin file from a computer to a 8 KBy device and read from the 8KBy device to the 256 KBy device.

Conditions:

- *.bin file has a maximum size of 256KB
- you can write at most 7.875KB to the 8KB device (other memory for flags)
- data is written from the computer to the 8KBy using ISO 15693 protocol
- data is read from the 8Kby to the 256KBy device via I2C at 400kHz protocol

I plan to break the .bin file into data chunks and calculate a CRC on a data chunk.

My questions are:

1. What would be the most efficient sized data chunk?
2. What would be the best CRC for that sized data chunk?

OR

1. What would be the best method to figure this information out?

Comment: Not sure what the data rate has to do with the question. You may want to think about your definition of "most efficient", and "best CRC". What error rate do you expect? How fast is your processor? What is the goal - fastest data transfer, lowest error rate? Sometimes adding some redundancy (self correction) makes the over all transmission faster although you send more bits "first time". It is likely this question will get closed as "too broad" unless you address some of these constraints. Interesting problem though.

Comment: See if your embedded processor has built in CRC generators - some are quite fast with a FIFO and such.  Can make CRC generation as easy as initialize, write, read, write, read, write, read,...

Comment: Most of the standard CRC's that I've seen (MD5, SHA ..etc) result in a fixed output. i.e MD5 always gives 32 characters (32 * 8 = 256 bits). Just pick anyone, subtract that from your data chunk ( 7.875KB - 32B = ???) and use the result as your 'new' chunk size.

Comment: When picking a CRC, there is a relation between the width of the polynomial, the amount of data and the severity of the errors (how many bits are changed when interference occurs). CRC algorithms are very good at finding single bit errors, decent at finding double bit errors and so-so at finding larger bit errors (bursts). The most common CRC polynomials are designed to be as efficient against all these kinds of different errors, so it is important to use a widely-recognized CRC algorithm. As for what to pick in your specific case, I don't know.

Comment: [A painless guide to CRC](http://www.ross.net/crc/download/crc_v3.txt) is recommended reading for all the details of how to implement CRC calculation.

Comment: @Floris I'm not sure what the error rate is to be honest. Is there a way to determine that? And the speed of the processor is up to 48MHz. The goal is ultimately lowest error rate, but I would like to make it as efficient as possible.

Comment: @chux Unfortunately, my embedded processor does not have a built in CRC generator ):

Comment: @chronodekar Do you have a preferred CRC?

Comment: @Lundin [32-Bit Cyclic Redundancy Codes for Internet Applications](http://www.ece.cmu.edu/~koopman/networks/dsn02/dsn02_koopman.pdf) This talks about the errors of using a common CRC. Is there validity to it?

Comment: Note: Recently was dealing with assessing an RF communication input whose data used a 16-bit CRC.  (Long sad story omitted here.) Bottom line: A 16-bit CRC assessment is fooled 1 in 65,536 times.  Wish system used 32-bit CRC (fooled 1 in 4 billion).